# Find an integral $ \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} \sinh(2ax) d x. $

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Find an integral
$$
\int\limits_0^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} \sinh(2ax) d x.
$$
Residue theorem. Or what?

Comment: $\sinh x = (e^x - e^{-x})/2$, so this is just a disguised Gaussian integral.

Comment: $5.3$ ? why not just 5 ?

Comment: I'm leaning toward suggesting "what". ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Mathematica obtains $\frac12 e^{a^2} \sqrt{\pi} \text{erf}(a)$ where erf is the error function. Since the error function isn't elementary, this integral won't have a nicer answer than this.

Comment: In the last 7 hours you.ve asked $5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3$, and I happen to notice that in none of those questions, have you shown any of your own work.

Comment: So, you want me to suggest something?

Comment: @Kamil: it is considered good to show [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960).

Comment: can fourier transform be use full here let $$ f(t)=e^{-t^{2}} \implies F(\omega_{0})=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-\dfrac{\omega^{2}_{0}}{4}} $$ and let $$ y(t)=x(t).\sinh (2at) \implies Y(\omega_{0})=\dfrac{1}{2}.\left[F(\omega_{0}-2a)-F(\omega_{0}+2a)\right] $$ @robjohn

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\sinh(2ax)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\left(e^{2ax}-e^{-2ax}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12e^{a^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-a)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,-\frac12e^{a^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-(x+a)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12e^{a^2}\int_{-a}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,-\frac12e^{a^2}\int_a^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12e^{a^2}\int_{-\infty}^a e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,-\frac12e^{a^2}\int_{-\infty}^{-a} e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12e^{a^2}\int_{-a}^a e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{a^2}\operatorname{erf}(a)
\end{align}
$$